# Se añade código a los archivos PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Hasta hace relativamente poco me está añadiendo esto a los archivos, no sé por qué será, ya que es local y no sé si realmente me afecta en algo.

```css
<style type="text/css">:root .GKJYXHBF2 > .GKJYXHBE2 > .GKJYXHBH5, :root a[href*="mfroute.com/"], :root a[href^="http://ffxitrack.com/"], :root a[href^="http://ad-apac.doubleclick.net/"], :root a[href^="http://www.amazon.co.uk/exec/obidos/external-search?"], :root #\5f _mom_ad_2, :root #rhs_block .mod > .luhb-div > div[data-async-type="updateHotelBookingModule"], :root #\5f _admvnlb_modal_container, :root #MAIN.ShowTopic > .ad, :root a[href^="https://www.arthrozene.com/"][href*="?tid="], :root a[href^="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/"], :root .GB3L-QEDGY .GB3L-QEDF- > .GB3L-QEDE-, :root #main_col > #center_col div[style="font-size:14px;margin:0 4px;padding:1px 5px;background:#fff7ed"], :root
.......
</style>
```

Nota: el navegador que uso es Opera y en Chrome me sale también.

Comment: En chrome me pasó de tener una extensión que agregaba eso. En opera desconozco. Fijate probando deshabilitandolos.

Comment: si yo pense lo mismo pero al desactivar las extensiones y crear un nuevo archivo al igual que abrir los que ya tengo me sige saliendo :(

Comment: al parecer si era la extension pero era una de opera que tiene no me abia dado cuenta, gracias como quiera :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe a que tienes una extensión bloqueadora de anuncios en tus navegadores, por lo que automáticamente añade esa propiedad de estilos en cascada.

Comment: a si al parecer el opera tiene algo asi pero ya es parte del opera, ya lo desabilite y si , thanks

Comment: Apreciaría elegir mi pregunta como la correcta si te ha ayudado a solucionar tu problema. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: si solo que me pide tiempo antes de eso :/